# Apache Jena vs Apache Marmotta

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, linked-data, apache-marmotta

What's the difference between Apache Jena and Apache Marmotta?

According to my readings both can be used for semantic web purposes. Both supports RDF,Triple store and so on. Both are based on Java. I hope this question will be valuable for those who are new to semantic web to solve the confusion.

- What are the main differences?
- How can I select which one to be used?

*Note that I'm **not** asking which one is **better**, What I'm asking is how to select one over the other depending on the usage/requirement/factors*

Comment: [This](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/marmotta-users/201312.mbox/%3C52A58A36.3000301@salzburgresearch.at%3E) seems relevant.

Comment: There is a common courtesy of letting the OP why did you press the close button. I don't know why this question should be closed.

Comment: @Technie "you" is not me (in case you thought so).

Comment: Okay. let me correct it "whoever the person who click the close button"

Comment: Also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/semanticweb/comments/2gsah7/apache_marmotta_an_open_platform_for_linked_data/) reddit post is useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Marmotta is a deployment ready Web Application used to expose existing data from Any DB(MySql/Sesame/Jena).
2. Jena is a RDF library simillar to Sesame.

Answer (score 3):

Both applications store RDF triples, offer a SPARQL endpoint and provide means to interact with semantic data.

Apache Marmotta is a complete web server for hosting, creating and modifying RDF data through HTTP requests using to the [W3C LDP spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/). You run it and you have a fully operational LDP server.

Apache Jena is a powerful RDF toolkit that offers many features to manipulate and query linked data. It's a powerful and versatile RDF library. However, it's not a standalone application like Marmotta.

Basically, if you need an LDP server, go with Marmotta. If you need to do other things with RDF in your project, Jena is probably the better option.

If you just need an HTTP endpoint for RDF data, perhaps [Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) (which is included in Jena) suits your needs.